# Replicate the Visual Studio 2005 interface

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, dockpanel

I was wondering how to replicate the `Visual Studio 2005` graphical user interface to create a [LOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_business) application. I have tried DevExpress controls but they cannot provide the `System` render mode. Then there is [DockPanelSuite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) which I like but when I'm using DevExpress it seems rather obvious that I would not use the [DockPanelSuite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/). When I'm using DevExpress with `UseWindowsXPTheme` option to true the menubar,toolbar seems to use the `ManagedRenderMode` which I don't want. I want to replicate the `Visual Studio 2005` as closely as possible. Can anyone please guide me to some project which already uses this. It'll be very helpful. Also I'm willing to use the MVP pattern for the development of this software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the SharpDevelop open source IDE which does this already.

Comment: SharpDevelop indeed is of the type I want but the interface feels a lot different from VS2005. Can you guide me to some other resource?

Comment: I think they have looked quite similar for some time now (SharpDevelop always trailing a bit behind the look of VS). Remember that if you want to replicate the look of VS circa 2005 you may have to look at SharpDevelops look cirka 2007? http://www.visualwebgui.com/Portals/0/QuickStarts/RunningaWinFormsApplicationInsideYourWebBrowser/vs2005-design.png    http://wayiam.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/1/917169.png

Comment: So the only thing I can do is wait? Well Thanks Anders for the help.

Comment: Wait? I added two screenshots, which show the VS2005 interface as well as an older version of SharpDevelop (one that quite closely resembles the VS2005 interface). If you wanted VS2010, then you would possibly have to wait.